# How can I reset associations?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

For CakePHP2, I used following function for resetting associations.

```
public function unbindModelAll($reset = true) {
    foreach(array('hasOne','hasMany','belongsTo','hasAndBelongsToMany') as $relation){
        $this->unbindModel(array($relation => array_keys($this->$relation)), $reset);
    }
}
```

How can I reset them for CakePHP3?

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 2.x you can easily clear bindings using empty contain on the model

```
$this->Model->contain();
```

For CakePHP 3.x you can try, I didn't test it:

```
$this->Model->find()->contain();
```